# SVG not displaying correctly

Tags: svg

Please refer to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3t5ajwL/5/. There are just two SVG symbols side by side. For some reason a small "_" appears between the two. Can someone explain what is going on? Each symbols displays fine by itself. The problem occurs when both are displayed at the same time.Tested on Chrome. Following code copied straight from jsfiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>      
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
  </style>   

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){

}//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="icon-home" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M16 9.5l-3-3v-4.5h-2v2.5l-3-3-8 8v0.5h2v5h5v-3h2v3h5v-5h2z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-android" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M13.5 5c-0.55 0-1 0.45-1 1v4c0 0.55 0.45 1 1 1s1-0.45 1-1v-4c0-0.55-0.45-1-1-1zM1.5 5c-0.55 0-1 0.45-1 1v4c0 0.55 0.45 1 1 1s1-0.45 1-1v-4c0-0.55-0.45-1-1-1zM3 11.5c0 0.828 0.672 1.5 1.5 1.5h0.5v2c0 0.55 0.45 1 1 1s1-0.45 1-1v-2h1v2c0 0.55 0.45 1 1 1s1-0.45 1-1v-2h0.5c0.828 0 1.5-0.672 1.5-1.5v-5.5h-9v5.5zM9.353 1.398l0.633-1.216c0.032-0.061 0.008-0.137-0.053-0.169s-0.137-0.008-0.169 0.053l-0.642 1.234c-0.503-0.195-1.050-0.301-1.622-0.301s-1.119 0.107-1.622 0.301l-0.642-1.234c-0.032-0.061-0.108-0.085-0.169-0.053s-0.085 0.108-0.053 0.169l0.633 1.216c-1.416 0.641-2.441 1.994-2.619 3.602h8.944c-0.178-1.608-1.203-2.961-2.619-3.602zM5.5 4.225c-0.4 0-0.725-0.325-0.725-0.725s0.325-0.725 0.725-0.725 0.725 0.325 0.725 0.725c-0 0.4-0.325 0.725-0.725 0.725zM9.5 4.225c-0.4 0-0.725-0.325-0.725-0.725s0.325-0.725 0.725-0.725 0.725 0.325 0.725 0.725c0 0.4-0.325 0.725-0.725 0.725z"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
<div class="home-icon" title="Home">
   <a href="/">
            <svg class="icon icon-home" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-home"></use>
            </svg>
    </a>
    <a href="/">
            <svg class="icon icon-android" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-android"></use>
            </svg>
    </a>
</div>      
</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That underline is caused by the `a` element. The inside inline-block content usually gives a space (rendered by a line-break) and this space is underlined. You can try setting `text-decoration:none` for the `a` element:

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t3t5ajwL/6/).

Another fix is write the closing tag `</a>` right after the `</svg>` tag. This way there will not be any line-break and the space as well as the underline will not be rendered:

```
<a href="/">
        <svg class="icon icon-home" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-home"></use>
        </svg></a>
<a href="/">
        <svg class="icon icon-android" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-android"></use>
        </svg></a>
```

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/t3t5ajwL/7/).